# Configure .htaccess to change HTTP GET parameters to URI

Tags: regex, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'd like to ask a simple question about `.htaccess`. I have a form from `index.html`, and would like to pass a value to `receiver.php`. How do you configure `.htaccess` to output `http://localhost/demo/receiver/jibberish` instead of `http://localhost/demo/receiver.php?fid=jibberish`?

**http://{host_name}/demo/index.html**

```
<form method="get" action="receiver.php">
  FID <input type="text" name="fid" value="jibberish"> <br>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit"> 
</form>
```

**http://{host_name}/demo/receiver.php**

```
<?php 
  echo $_GET['fid'];
?>
```

I'm having a hard time. Here is my `.htaccess` code.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1 -f
RewriteRule ^/receiver.php$ /receiver.php?fid=$1 [PT]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: It is not clear what you want. I guess it is about showing a "pretty" URL without queries, like `/receiver/jibberish`, instead of `receiver.php?fid=$1` with the query, but still map silently the last one to the resource (receiver.php). If that's the case, it is possible, but what group is `$1` back reference pointing to and why are you using `PT` flag? That flag is implied in per-directory context and not needed normally. Give one example of the complete URL sent by the form without $1 or back references impossible to guess, please.

Comment: I apologize about that. I have updated the url to represent clearly HTTP GET on fid.

Answer (score 2):

Enable mod_rewrite and .htaccess through `httpd.conf` and then put this code in your `.htaccess` under `DOCUMENT_ROOT` directory:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s/+(receiver)\.php\?fid=([^\s]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1/%2? [R=302,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(receiver)/(.+?)/?$ /$1.php?fid=$2 [L,NC,QSA]
```

Once you verify it is working fine, replace `R=302` to `R=301`. Avoid using `R=301` (Permanent Redirect) while testing your mod_rewrite rules.

Comment: @FranzNoel: Do you have another .htaccess under `/demo` directory by any chance?

Answer (score 1):

This should work in one .htaccess file at root directory:

```
Options +FollowSymlinks -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /demo/receiver.php\?fid=([^&\s]+) [NC]
RewriteRule  .*            /demo/receiver/%1?  [R=301,L,NC]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}  !receiver\.php [NC]
RewriteRule  ^demo/receiver/([^/]+)/?  /demo/receiver.php?fid=$1 [L,NC]
```

Comment: Thanks for this solution. It helped a lot. I apologize for changing the url in the question because it does not reflect the real problem. I'm having a hard time putting in the directory.

Comment: Okay. Looking at your question with the last update, I see the `/demo` directory is missing in the answer. I modified it accordingly.

Comment: I have tried that. However it still redirects to `http://localhost/receiver/jibberish` instead of `http://localhost/demo/receiver/jibberish`

Comment: Hi, I have read all the answers and try to do the suggested solutions. But in the end, I got "Object Not Found" warning. The URL is correct http://localhost/demo/receiver/jibberish. Can anyone help?